# SSIS - specify only one parameter in OLE DB Source with multiple '?'

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

when writing my SQL command I specify `?` to indicate that I want to use a passed in Parameter. However, for every `?` I use, the package thinks it's a new parameter even though I want to use the same one.

[image]

6 `?` = 6 new parameters though each parameter is the same. As seen on parameter 0 and 1

Is there a way that I can specify just one parameter?

Thanks

Comment: you can declare a variable, pass it a parameter and use it in the Where clause. take a look to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by declaring a variable in you SQL Command and pass it a parameter then use this variable in the `WHERE` clause. like the following

```
DECLARE @str AS INT

SET @str = ?

SELECT        Column1
FROM            Table1
WHERE        (Column2= @str or Column3 = @str)
```

[image]

[image]

**Other Workarounds**

**1)**

*Assuming you want to create the following query*

```
Select * From Table1 Where [Column1] = ? Or [Column2] = ?
```

1. Declare a variable (ex: `User::strQuery`)
2. Store your parameter in a variable (ex: `User::Value`)
3. Set the variable `EvaluateAsExpression` property to True
4. Set the expression to the following:

   ```
   "Select * From Table1 Where [Column1] = " + @[User::Value] + " OR [Column2] = " + @[User::Value]
   ```
5. In the `OLEDB Source` Set the source to `SQL Command from variable` and choose the variable `@[User::strQuery]`

**2)**

You can create a stored procedure or a table-valued function that take one parameter and use it as source

Comment: I see, that was pretty simple to be fair. I am ashamed of my question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you declare a variable inside your SQL statement script that takes the value of the parameter via the ?, and then use the variable after that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure on SQL Server that takes one parameter and contains the correct query. Invoke the stored procedure with the one parameter.